# SublimeREPL IPython opening regular inte

Tags: ipython, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

Versions:  Sublime Text 3, sublimeREPL 2.1.1, ipython 2.3.1, python 2.7.9, using OSX Yosemite

When I try to open an ipython interpreter through sublimeREPL, I get a regular python interpreter.  No warnings or error messages.

If I navigate to /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python  and type python -u ipy_repl.py then it does indeed open an ipython interpreter.  It seems like the the wrong command is being executed, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I added the full python path to `Main.sublime-menu`.

I had tried making changes to `default_extend_env` in `SublimeREPL.sublime-settings`, but was unable to to get Ipython REPL working that way.

From `Command Palette` select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`

Choose `SublimeREPL`->`config/`->`Python/`->`Main.sublime-menu`

In my case, I added the full python path to `osx`.

```
"cmd": {
       "osx": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
       "linux": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
       "windows": ["python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"]
},
```